# Stable-Baselines3 package, model.learn() function - how do total_timesteps and num_eval_episodes work together?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am using the SB3 package for RL, and I'm trying out the model.learn() function.

I don't understand exactly what model.learn() parameters do in terms of how they work together and with my environment.

My RL is working from a tabular dataset, so there's an inherent limitation to number of timesteps possible.

Let's say these are my conditions:

1. I have a dataset with 20,000 rows (possible timesteps)
2. In my environment, my step() function contains an if-statement which flips "done" to True when the number of steps taken reaches 1,000 (the step() function counts the number of times it's been called since the initialization of the env).
3. I run model.learn() with total_timesteps = 30,000 .

I encounter no errors when I do this. Can someone please explain what is happening? Is model.learn() running my environment through the first 1,000 timesteps, then re-starts and keeps looping this way until 30,000 total timesteps have been taken?

If so, how does num_eval_episodes feed into this? Does it change how the function runs? If so, how?

I'm sorry for the scattered question, I appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with SB3 as well these days and I think your own assessment that "*model.learn() is running the environment through the first 1,000 timesteps, then re-starts and keeps looping this way until 30,000 total timesteps have been taken*" is probably correct.
Have you ever set the if-statement that flips "done" to True to a number of steps greater than your dataset?

As far as I know SB3 works that way so that you can train on environments with or without a fixed number of timesteps without getting problems with infinite training in cases where the terminal state is never reached.

In my own application which also has episodes with a fixed number of timesteps per episode (*n_max_timesteps*) I always set "*total_timesteps*=*n_episodes***n_max_timesteps*" in model.learn().

"n_eval_episodes" runs the agent for a specified number of episodes from reset to reaching a final / terminal state.